# Storing an api_key, api_pass

Tags: python

I want to store a user's API_KEY and API_PASSWORD, obscured in my database. I do need to be readily view them (for authentication) and to be able to display to the user if they want to view it. What would be a good way to do this?

```
def create_key(self, user):
    key = str(uuid.uuid4()).replace('-','')
    key_saved_in_database = # ?
    user.key = key_saved_in_database
    user.save()

def view_key(self, user):
    key_saved_in_database = user.key
    key = # ?
    return key
```

What are some possible ways to do this?

Comment: xor the key with a secret key and xor again with the same key would be enough for you? (It is not so safe though.)

Comment: Yes, that would work for the given circumstance.

Comment: Encrypt them with a symmetric key (with a real encryption algorithm like AES, not with XOR), and then store that symmetric key *securely* external to the database, so that if the database is compromised (say, through a SQL injection vulnerability), the passwords aren't compromised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic implementation with xoring might look like this:

```
def infiniteSecret(secret):
    num = 0
    while true:
        yield secret[num % len(secret)]
        num += 1
#one direction
key_saved_in_database = map(lambda a, b: a ^ b, zip(infiniteSecret(secret), key))

#other direction
key = map(lambda a, b: a ^ b, zip(infiniteSecret(secret), key_saved_in_database))
```